# php same parameters different value

Tags: php, wordpress, parameters

I have a Wordpress plugin that when searching multiple types of cars ads multiple values of the same parameter in the url.

```
/home/?condition=filter1&condition=filter2&s=
```

Now I created multiple user roles for different cars and want to add a filter to the site.
This code works with 1 value

```
function wprdcv_param_redirect() {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    $url_parts = parse_url("http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    parse_str($url_parts['query'], $params);


    if( ! empty( $user ) && count( array_intersect( [ "userrole1" ], (array) $user->roles ) ) ) {
        //Prevent infinite loop
        if ($_GET["condition"] == "filter1") return;
        $params["condition"] = "filter1";
        $params["s"] = "";
    }
    else {
        //Prevent infinite loop
        if ($_GET["condition"] == "") return;
        $params["condition"] = "";
        $params["s"] = "";
    }

    foreach (array_keys($_GET) as $n) {
        $params[$n] = $_GET[$n];
    }

    // Note that this will url_encode all values
    $url_parts['query'] = http_build_query($params);
    wp_redirect(http_build_url($url_parts));
    exit;
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wprdcv_param_redirect');
```

When I add the following it offcourse overwrites the value and only shows the last one:

```
if ($_GET["condition"] == "filter1") return;
        $params["condition"] = "filter1";
        $params["condition"] = "filter2";
        $params["s"] = "";
```

how can I edit this so it shows me 2 same parameters with different values?

**EDIT:**

I have adding following and it works like a charm!

```
    $params["condition"][] = "Filter1";
    $params["condition"][] = "Filter2";
```

Thx fellas! [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) & [@Vincent Decaux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999617/vincent-decaux)

/home/?condition%5B0%5D=Filter1&condition%5B1%5D=Filter2&s=  proves to be perfectly working

Comment: You have to use an array to define multiple params, like : `/home/?condition[]=filter1&condition[]=filter2&s=`, or yes of course, your params will always be overrided

Comment: Why not just do a POST request and submit a JSON structure with an array?

Comment: `$params["condition"][] = "new_filter_value";`